# How to use background camera and foreground camera simultaneously?

Tags: android, android-camera

My new application requirement is client wants to create a spy camera which record the video in background. Now whenever the phone is lock and user is not present so in the absens of user someone try to use the phone it will start video recording in background recording. I have done all this thing and it works like a charm no issue with this.

Now the problem is when the service start video recording in background and at that time I open my default camera app and it won't allow me to use the camera application that is but obvious because my service using that camera in background.

So my question is that can we use both background camera and foreground camera simultaneously? AFAIK it is not possible to use background camera and foreground camera.

As I searched on stack overflow someone said that Samsung s4 default application do that you can capture front and back and its I have s4 and its default application do that thing but when I installed and use my app it raise the same issue.

Right now I am planning to stop video recording when my default camera application open. But is their any other way apart from stop recording?